# How to serialize db.Model objects to json?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, simplejson

When using

```
from django.utils import simplejson
```

on objects of types that derive from `db.Model` it throws exceptions. How to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find an appropriate solution I wrote my own, which is not exactly a JSON serializer, but a Javascript serializer

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api.datastore_types import *

def dumpStr(obj):
    return "'" + obj + "'"

def dumps(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return dumpStr(obj)
    elif obj == None:
        return None
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        items = [];
        for item in obj:
            items.append(dumps(item))
        return '[' + ','.join(items) + ']'
    elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        return "new Date('%s')" % obj.ctime()
    properties = [];
    for property in dir(obj):
        if property[0] != '_':
            value = obj.__getattribute__(property)
            valueClass = str(value.__class__)
            if not(('function' in valueClass) or ('built' in valueClass) or ('method' in valueClass)):
                value = dumps(value)
                if value != None:
                    properties.append("'" + property + "':" + value)
    if len(properties) == 0:
        return str(obj)
    else:
        return '{' + ','.join(properties) + '}'
```

Comment: Just a warning: this will *not* produce valid JSON for all inputs. For example, if a string contains a `'` or a `\n` the JSON will be invalid, or if the obj contains a number. So **don't use this** — use top-voted answer.

Answer (score 14):

Ok - my python not great so any help would be appreciated - You dont need to write a parser - this is the solution:

add this utlity class http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/geochat/json.py?r=55

```
 import datetime  
 import time 

 from google.appengine.api import users 
 from google.appengine.ext import db 

#this is a mod on the orinal file for some reason it includes its own simplejson files i have ref django!
 from django.utils import simplejson  

 class GqlEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder): 

   """Extends JSONEncoder to add support for GQL results and properties. 

   Adds support to simplejson JSONEncoders for GQL results and properties by 
   overriding JSONEncoder's default method. 
   """ 

   # TODO Improve coverage for all of App Engine's Property types. 

   def default(self, obj): 

     """Tests the input object, obj, to encode as JSON.""" 

     if hasattr(obj, '__json__'): 
       return getattr(obj, '__json__')() 

     if isinstance(obj, db.GqlQuery): 
       return list(obj) 

     elif isinstance(obj, db.Model): 
       properties = obj.properties().items() 
       output = {} 
       for field, value in properties: 
         output[field] = getattr(obj, field) 
       return output 

     elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime): 
       output = {} 
       fields = ['day', 'hour', 'microsecond', 'minute', 'month', 'second', 
           'year'] 
       methods = ['ctime', 'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 
           'timetuple'] 
       for field in fields: 
         output[field] = getattr(obj, field) 
       for method in methods: 
         output[method] = getattr(obj, method)() 
       output['epoch'] = time.mktime(obj.timetuple()) 
       return output 

     elif isinstance(obj, time.struct_time): 
       return list(obj) 

     elif isinstance(obj, users.User): 
       output = {} 
       methods = ['nickname', 'email', 'auth_domain'] 
       for method in methods: 
         output[method] = getattr(obj, method)() 
       return output 

     return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj) 


 def encode(input): 
   """Encode an input GQL object as JSON 

     Args: 
       input: A GQL object or DB property. 

     Returns: 
       A JSON string based on the input object.  

     Raises: 
       TypeError: Typically occurs when an input object contains an unsupported 
         type. 
     """ 
   return GqlEncoder().encode(input)
```

**save as json.py**

TO USE

```
import cgi
import os
import json 

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db


class Greeting(db.Model):
    author = db.UserProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        greetings_query = Greeting.all().order('-date')
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(5)

        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_values = {
            'greetings': greetings,
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
            }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))


class Guestbook(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        greeting = Greeting()

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user()

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        greeting.put()
        self.redirect('/')



#here i return my json feed - simple implementaion for example
class FeedHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    """Retrieve a feed"""
    user = None

    greetings_query = Greeting.all().order('-date')
    rs= greetings_query.fetch(5)
#this is the part that calls the encoder - dosnt cause an exception
    data = json.encode(rs)



#roll out to browser -might need to check my headers etc
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'  
    self.response.out.write(data)




application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                       [
                                       ('/', MainPage),
                                       ('/sign',Guestbook),
                                       ('/feed',FeedHandler),
                                       ], debug=True
                                    )

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the browser response:

> [{"content": "", "date": {"ctime": "Sat Jan 23 02:40:22 2010", "hour": 2, "isoweekday": 6, "month": 1, "second": 22, "microsecond": 434000, "isocalendar": [2010, 3, 6], "timetuple": [2010, 1, 23, 2, 40, 22, 5, 23, -1], "year": 2010, "epoch": 1264214422.0, "isoformat": "2010-01-23T02:40:22.434000", "day": 23, "minute": 40}, "author": {"nickname": "test@example.com", "email": "test@example.com", "auth_domain": "gmail.com"}}, {"content": "", "date": {"ctime": "Sat Jan 23 01:12:43 2010", "hour": 1, "isoweekday": 6, "month": 1, "second": 43, "microsecond": 972000, "isocalendar": [2010, 3, 6], "timetuple": [2010, 1, 23, 1, 12, 43, 5, 23, -1], "year": 2010, "epoch": 1264209163.0, "isoformat": "2010-01-23T01:12:43.972000", "day": 23, "minute": 12}, "author": {"nickname": "test@example.com", "email": "test@example.com", "auth_domain": "gmail.com"}}, {"content": "test", "date": {"ctime": "Fri Jan 22 22:32:13 2010", "hour": 22, "isoweekday": 5, "month": 1, "second": 13, "microsecond": 659000, "isocalendar": [2010, 3, 5], "timetuple": [2010, 1, 22, 22, 32, 13, 4, 22, -1], "year": 2010, "epoch": 1264199533.0, "isoformat": "2010-01-22T22:32:13.659000", "day": 22, "minute": 32}, "author": {"nickname": "test@example.com", "email": "test@example.com", "auth_domain": "gmail.com"}}, {"content": "", "date": {"ctime": "Fri Jan 22 22:29:49 2010", "hour": 22, "isoweekday": 5, "month": 1, "second": 49, "microsecond": 358000, "isocalendar": [2010, 3, 5], "timetuple": [2010, 1, 22, 22, 29, 49, 4, 22, -1], "year": 2010, "epoch": 1264199389.0, "isoformat": "2010-01-22T22:29:49.358000", "day": 22, "minute": 29}, "author": {"nickname": "test@example.com", "email": "test@example.com", "auth_domain": "gmail.com"}}, {"content": "ah it works!\r\n", "date": {"ctime": "Fri Jan 22 22:29:22 2010", "hour": 22, "isoweekday": 5, "month": 1, "second": 22, "microsecond": 995000, "isocalendar": [2010, 3, 5], "timetuple": [2010, 1, 22, 22, 29, 22, 4, 22, -1], "year": 2010, "epoch": 1264199362.0, "isoformat": "2010-01-22T22:29:22.995000", "day": 22, "minute": 29}, "author": {"nickname": "test@example.com", "email": "test@example.com", "auth_domain": "gmail.com"}}]

Comment: I was implementing my own and it is so close to the file you linked

Comment: Was not immediately apparent to me (python and GAE newbie) but you need to include the simplejson module code into your GAE files/packages.

Comment: How to use this for db model having Reference property? (I have one db class which hv another db model reference and this soln is not working)

Comment: i get this: tuple: ('datetime.date(2011, 2, 24) is not JSON serializable',)

Comment: Note that GAE on Python 2.7 now includes the json module as a replacement to django.utils.simplejson so if you're using 2.7, the reference should be changed and the file will probably have to be renamed.  I also added a line in in the db.Model case that says `output['key'] = str(obj.Key())`  That way I can refer to the key for posting updates later and whatnot.

Answer (score 10):

The example provided by Jader Dias works fine for my concern after some tweaking. Remove the encode method as it contains a circular reference. The adjusted class should look like:

```
import datetime  
import time 

from google.appengine.api import users 
from google.appengine.ext import db 
from django.utils import simplejson  


class GqlEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder): 

    """Extends JSONEncoder to add support for GQL results and properties. 

    Adds support to simplejson JSONEncoders for GQL results and properties by 
    overriding JSONEncoder's default method. 
    """ 

    # TODO Improve coverage for all of App Engine's Property types. 

    def default(self, obj): 

        """Tests the input object, obj, to encode as JSON.""" 

        if hasattr(obj, '__json__'): 
            return getattr(obj, '__json__')() 

        if isinstance(obj, db.GqlQuery): 
            return list(obj) 
        
        elif isinstance(obj, db.Model): 
            properties = obj.properties().items() 
            output = {} 
            for field, value in properties: 
                output[field] = getattr(obj, field) 
            return output 
        
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime): 
            output = {} 
            fields = ['day', 'hour', 'microsecond', 'minute', 'month', 'second', 'year'] 
            methods = ['ctime', 'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 'timetuple'] 
            for field in fields: 
                output[field] = getattr(obj, field) 
            for method in methods: 
                output[method] = getattr(obj, method)() 
            output['epoch'] = time.mktime(obj.timetuple()) 
            return output

        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.date): 
            output = {} 
            fields = ['year', 'month', 'day'] 
            methods = ['ctime', 'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 'timetuple'] 
            for field in fields: 
                output[field] = getattr(obj, field) 
            for method in methods: 
                output[method] = getattr(obj, method)() 
            output['epoch'] = time.mktime(obj.timetuple()) 
            return output 
        
        elif isinstance(obj, time.struct_time): 
            return list(obj) 
        
        elif isinstance(obj, users.User): 
            output = {} 
            methods = ['nickname', 'email', 'auth_domain'] 
            for method in methods: 
                output[method] = getattr(obj, method)() 
            return output 
        
        return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

As I've saved this class in a file called `utils.py` and when appropriate I import it using

```
import utils
```

Then I just call `utils.GqlEncoder().encode(results)`, for example:

```
query = User.all()
results = query.fetch(10)
            
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain" # Alt. application/json
self.response.out.write( utils.GqlEncoder().encode(results) )
```

The result should look something like this (I've added some line feeds in order to make it a bit easier to read):

```
[
{"date": {"ctime": "Tue Feb 23 10:41:21 2010", "hour": 10, "isoweekday": 2, "month": 2, 
        "second": 21, "microsecond": 495535, "isocalendar": [2010, 8, 2], "timetuple": [2010, 2, 23, 10, 41, 21, 1, 54, -1], 
        "year": 2010, "epoch": 1266921681.0, "isoformat": "2010-02-23T10:41:21.495535", "day": 23, "minute": 41}, 
"claimed_id": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/accounts\/o8\/id?id=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz", 
"display_name": "Alfred E Neumann", 
"email": null, 
"full_name": "Alfred E Neumann"
}, 
{"date": {"ctime": "Tue Feb 23 11:00:54 2010", "hour": 11, "isoweekday": 2, "month": 2, 
        "second": 54, "microsecond": 805261, "isocalendar": [2010, 8, 2], "timetuple": [2010, 2, 23, 11, 0, 54, 1, 54, -1], 
        "year": 2010, "epoch": 1266922854.0, "isoformat": "2010-02-23T11:00:54.805261", "day": 23, "minute": 0}, 
"claimed_id": "http:\/\/openid.domain.net\/john", 
"display_name": "", 
"email": "jd@domain.net", 
"full_name": "John Doe"
}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

json cannot be used to serialize anything more than basic types such as dicts, lists, ints/longs, and strings (this is not comprehensive). For example, even these simple commands do not work:

```
import json
json.dumps(object())
```

If you want to serialize django objects, you should refer to the [django documentation on serialization](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/), which will use their own libraries, but they do do support json.

Comment: By the way, the json library which is included in Python 2.6 is functionally equivalent to simplejson.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Jader means the appengine db.Model objects, not the django ones.

Comment: it won't work with Google App Engine `db.Model`, because `simplejson.dumps` returns `object is not JSON serializable`   and `serializers.serialize` returns `object has no attribute '_meta'`

Answer (score -1):

From what i can understand - and i am new to python - with google app engine the work around is to serialize the model object to a dictioanry python object and then use simple json to dump it as a json string - this makes no sense to me - maybe someone has the know to serialise to a ditionary (pickel?)
Any help on this would be HELP! not to impressed that google app engine has no inbuilt solution for this.

Comment: tried the code and got this error "return GqlEncoder().encode(input)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"